# Request Token from ADFS STS - DirectReference, disable Renewing

Tags: cxf, ws-security

I am trying to use Apache CXF with policy based WS-Security. 
The WSDL file tells the client to first get a token from a Security Token Service.
This Request needs to be signed with a certificate i got from the service provider. The STS is implemented using [ADFS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb897402.aspx).

My current code looks like this:

```
BindingProvider bindingProvider = (BindingProvider) port;
Map<String, Object> requestContext = bindingProvider.getRequestContext();

// signing configuration
Properties cryptoProperties = new Properties();
cryptoProperties.put(Merlin.PREFIX + Merlin.KEYSTORE_TYPE, "pkcs12");
cryptoProperties.put(Merlin.PREFIX + Merlin.KEYSTORE_FILE, "C:\\[...]\\keystore.p12");
cryptoProperties.put(Merlin.PREFIX + Merlin.KEYSTORE_PASSWORD, KEYSTORE_KEY);
cryptoProperties.put(Merlin.PREFIX + Merlin.KEYSTORE_ALIAS, KEYSTORE_ALIAS);
requestContext.put(SecurityConstants.SIGNATURE_CRYPTO, new Merlin(cryptoProperties, Loader.getClassLoader(Merlin.class), null));
requestContext.put(SecurityConstants.SIGNATURE_USERNAME, KEYSTORE_ALIAS);
requestContext.put(SecurityConstants.CALLBACK_HANDLER,
    new CallbackHandler() {
        @Override
        public void handle(Callback[] callbacks)
            throws IOException, UnsupportedCallbackException {
        WSPasswordCallback pc = (WSPasswordCallback) callbacks[0];
        pc.setPassword(KEYSTORE_KEY);
    }
});

// additional configuration
requestContext.put(SecurityConstants.STS_CLIENT_SOAP12_BINDING, "true");
```

Currently i get the error *ID3035: The request was not valid or is malformed.*

The policy looks like this

```
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="[...]">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
        <wsp:All>
            <sp:TransportBinding xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:TransportToken>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:HttpsToken RequireClientCertificate="false"/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:TransportToken>
                    <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:Basic256/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                    <sp:Layout>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:Strict/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:Layout>
                    <sp:IncludeTimestamp/>
                </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:TransportBinding>
            <sp:EndorsingSupportingTokens xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:X509Token sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:RequireThumbprintReference/>
                            <sp:WssX509V3Token10/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:X509Token>
                    <mssp:RsaToken sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/Never" wsp:Optional="true" xmlns:mssp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy"/>
                    <sp:SignedParts>
                        <sp:Header Name="To" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
                    </sp:SignedParts>
                </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:EndorsingSupportingTokens>
            <sp:Wss11 xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:MustSupportRefThumbprint/>
                </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:Wss11>
            <sp:Trust10 xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:MustSupportIssuedTokens/>
                    <sp:RequireClientEntropy/>
                    <sp:RequireServerEntropy/>
                </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:Trust10>
            <wsaw:UsingAddressing/>
        </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
```

The example of the service provider tells me to sign the request this way:

```
<Security>
    <BinarySecurityToken Id="uuid-something">[...]</BinarySecurityToken>
    <Signature>
        [...]
        <KeyInfo>
            <SecurityTokenReference>
                <Reference URI="#uuid-something"></Reference>
            </SecurityTokenReference>
        </KeyInfo>
    </Signature>
</Security>
```

My request looks like this:

```
<Security>
    <BinarySecurityToken>[...]</BinarySecurityToken>
    <Signature>
        [...]
        <KeyInfo>
            <SecurityTokenReference>
                <KeyIdentifier>[...]</KeyIdentifier>
            </SecurityTokenReference>
        </KeyInfo>
    </Signature>
</Security>
```

How do i manage to get a **Reference** instead of the *KeyIdentifier*?

Searching the internet i think i somehow have to set [WSHandlerConstants.SIG_KEY_ID](http://ws.apache.org/wss4j/config.html) to *DirectReference* like stated in this [blog-post](http://coheigea.blogspot.co.at/2013/03/signature-and-encryption-key.html).
The problem is i don't know how to do that with the policy based approach...

Another difference to the working example is, that my request contains **<Renewing />**, which does not work with ADFS like [stated in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24485837/3994580).

```
<wst:RequestSecurityToken>
    [...]
    <wst:Renewing/>
</wst:RequestSecurityToken>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does the policy look like? It should tell CXF how to reference the signing key, without any configuration changes.

The policy clearly tells CXF to use a Thumbprint Reference to refer to the signing key, so CXF is doing the right thing as per the policy. If you want to use a direct reference, then remove the "RequireThumbprintReference" policy.

You can avoid sending the Renewing Element by setting the "sendRenewing" of the STSClient to "false".