# how to configure user in ADFS to be able to access CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, adfs

I am trying to follow this post to let my web application authenticate with ADFS before calling CRM.
[Apache CXF client for claims-mode xRM (Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24144629/apache-cxf-client-for-claims-mode-xrm-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011/61002120#61002120)

I am not sure what kind of user I should create in ADFS in order to access CRM. What is the proper permission or user roles?

Also UserNameWSTrustBinding_IWSTrust13Async policy uses this endpoint https://yourcompany.com/adfs/services/trust/13/UsernameMixed

Do I need to disable this endpoint to make my app work? It was mentioned here the endpoint needs to be disabled.
https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/144495/the-authentication-endpoint-username-was-not-found-on-the-configured-secure-token-service